# How Do I Combine More Than 2 Normal Maps?

Tags: animation

Hi I've been looking everywhere and I found an answer but it still doesn't apply to what I'm asking. I'm new with Cycles and have trouble with it, but I was wondering how I can combine more then two normal maps? I have different image textures and want to apply them all to a model without having to adjust a factor or whatever, and this is my set up so far:

[image]

If I can get some help and get an uncomplicated node set up that would be amazing, anyways thanks guys!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30953/how-can-i-layer-two-images-to-be-used-as-height-information-in-a-bump-node-whi/30964#30964 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80327/combining-normals and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/using-a-normal-map-together-with-a-bump-map/16447#16447

Comment: Also related: https://i.imgur.com/u8cE9Ur.jpg and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30953/how-can-i-layer-two-images-to-be-used-as-height-information-in-a-bump-node-whi/30964#30964 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55232/how-to-properly-hook-up-various-maps-types-together-in-cycles/55254#55254